# Is there a way for nodejs' "net" module to determine if a data packet is the last packet in a sequence?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, client

I'm getting a large amount of json data from a TCP Server.  I can successfully connect to the server with nodejs' "net" module and send the packet to request the data from it.  The server sends the data back in packets, of course, so I have a listener which gets the string data from each packet and stores it in a string buffer.

[image: screenshot of described code]

The issue is that net's data event doesn't offer any indication of whether a packet is the last packet in the sequence or not.  In Wireshark, I can clearly see that the last packet is the one with the PSH flag:

[image: screenshot of described wireshark packet]

but there's no way to look at flags or packet details with net, only data.

I looked within the net documentation for other events which might indicate the last packet in the sequence.  I tried using the end event, but this was not correct.  I took every event in the documentation and put a simple event listener on it to log when it was fired, and the only one which fired at the last packet was the data event.  I tried seeing if maybe there were a few extra bytes in the data which contained extra details, but net only returns data.  I tried looking into net's source code, but I'm too inexperienced to figure out the problem from there.

This might be a dumb question, but I'm just too inexperienced with net to figure out how to do this, and every simple tutorial for a TCP client in node js just says that you can listen for data packets with the data event.  If nothing else works, I can just look for the packet whose last character is a '}' to indicate the end of the JSON object, but I imagine this could cause bigger issues down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Plain TCP does not have something like this.  This is why most data is sent using a "protocol" such as http or webSocket because the protocol defines when a given set of data begins and ends.

You can either make your own rudimentary protocol or you can adopt an existing one (probably using client and server code that already implements that protocol.

For example, if you used the webSocket protocol, then data will already be collected into a message for you.

If you want to build your own rudimentary protocol, you could send the length of your data first either as 4 bytes of binary or as a string of ascii digits followed by a space and then send your data and the receiving code would then know exactly how many bytes of data to read before the end of the data by parsing that initial length.

If this connection is only being used for this one transaction, you could just have the sender close the connection when they are done sending and the closing of the connection on the receiving end would signify the end of the data.  The problem with that scheme is that you can't necessarily tell the difference between a completed connection versus an interrupted connection.

If you control both client and server, I would personally probably use either http or webSocket for this rather than design my own protocol.  If this is a one-time connect, send, disconnect, I'd use http.  If this is a long lasting connection over which you will send many messages, I'd use webSocket.